# Weird URLs for images from Assets

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic, wygwam, low-variables

I'm troubleshooting a problem with an older, rarely updated site, so I'm not sure how recently this issue cropped up, though I'm fairly certain it worked when I handed it off. We have a Low Variable set as a Wygwam field using Assets for images. When we use Asssets to insert images into the field, we get an img tag with an src like this.

```
{assets_795:http://domain.com{filedir_5}1382581981.jpg}
```

Any idea what's going on there?

- EE 2.7.2
- Wygwam 3.2.2
- Assets 2.2.2
- Low Variable 2.4.0

UPDATE: It just occurred to me that the EE server this site lives on (which is multi-site) has had these add ons updated since I built the site, though I'm not sure how relevant that is to this particular issue.

Answer (score 0):

How is the LV called? It should be called using the Parse or Single tag to process those unparsed vars, eg:

```
{exp:low_variables:single var="my_wygwam_var"}
```

Comment: Appreciate the response. I was indeed using the global variable syntax, but I tried parse, single, and pair all with the same result.